# LinearLayout can not get orientation from styles

Tags: android, styles, orientation, android-linearlayout

I have a style for my linear layouts with orientation defined inside.
The problem is that eclipse says:
 "No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal. This is a common source of bugs when children are added dynamically."
But I've specified orientation in styles. how to solve this problem?
This is my style:

```
<style name="linearVertical">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>
```

This is the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
===============
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

=================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do like this you have to add layout_width and layout_height  in your layouts xml.

Comment: and what about my problem?(orientation)

Comment: Orientation should also be in xml.

Answer (score 0):

because your LinearLayout has nothing 
you can add a textview or imageview ,then the problem will disappear

Comment: or you can add" <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>" in your style file